# Python, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_model'

Tags: python

when calling both my get_year function and my get_model function i receive the error  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute in the case of my find_cars_by_year function it iterates through the entire car list but doesn't compare the year to my inputted year how would i correctly call my getter methods in order to avoid errors?

```
enter code here
class Car:
    def __init__(self,model,year,registration_number):
        self.__model=model
        self.__year=year
        self.__registration_number=registration_number

    def get_model(self):
        return self.__model

    def get_year(self):
        return self.__year

    def get_registration_number(self):
        return self.__registration_number

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.__model+" "+self.__registration_number+" "+(str) self.__year))
class Service:
    def __init__(self, car_list):
        self.__car_list=car_list 

    def get_car_list(self):
        return self.__car_list
    def find_cars_by_year(self, year):
        self.year= year
        car_by_year_list=[]
        for i in self.get_car_list():
            if i.get_year()==self.year :
                car_by_year_list.append(i)
        if car_by_year_list==[]:
            return None
        else:
            return car_by_year_list




    def add_cars(self,new_car_list):
        self.new_car_list=new_car_list
        return self.get_car_list().append(self.new_car_list)

    def remove_cars_from_karnataka(self):
        for i in self.get_car_list():
            if i.get_model()[0:2]=="KA":
                self.get_car_list().remove(i)



car1=Car("WagonR",2010,"KA09 3056")
car2=Car("Beat", 2011, "MH10 6776")
car3=Car("Ritz", 2013,"KA12 9098")
car4=Car("Polo",2013,"GJ01 7854")
car5=Car("Amaze",2014,"KL07 4332")
#Add different values to the list and test the program
car_list=[car1, car2, car3, car4,car5]
car_list2=[car2,car3]
s=Service(car_list)

s.add_cars(car_list2)
s.remove_cars_from_karnataka()
print(s.get_car_list()[1].get_year())
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: return self.get_car_list().append(self.new_car_list), instead of append use extend to add list items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `add_cars()` method isn't doing what it should be doing here:

```
return self.get_car_list().append(self.new_car_list)
```

When I print `i` in your `remove_cars_from_karnataka` method, I see the following:

```
WagonR KA09 3056 2010
Beat MH10 6776 2011
Ritz KA12 9098 2013
Polo GJ01 7854 2013
Amaze KL07 4332 2014
[<__main__.Car object at 0x00000239D51EEAC8>, <__main__.Car object at 0x00000239D51EEA20>]
```

The first 5 are the ones you originally had, and the two others are the ones you added later on. So the list of cars you gave to `remove_cars_from_karnataka` is a list of strings but with the last element of the list being another list (nested list). From there, you get the error you mentioned. I guess you could do it like this instead:

```
def add_cars(self,new_car_list):
    for new_car in new_car_list:
        self.get_car_list().append(new_car)
```

Comment: Also, you can see a lot of things if you try to `print` it yourself. I'm sure you would have seen the issue if you `print`ed the values of `i` like I mentioned in my post.